# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method (boolean)

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

I have this Linq with EF6 :

```cs
private Expression<Func<contact, bool>> FilterBuilder()
{
    Expression<Func<contact, bool>> filter = t => true;
    filter = filter.AndAlso(contact => ContactBLL.IsAUser(contact.echange.id.GetValueOrDefault()));
    // Error LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method
    return filter;
}
```

IsAUser returns boolean, how can I propertly use this methos without rewriting it ?

Comment: You either have to replace it with logic that can be translated to SQL by EF or you'll have to use it in memory by getting the results via `AsEnumerable` or `ToList` and then continuing to filter with your method.  Obviously the latter results in pulling more from the DB, but may be necessary based on whatever your method does.

Comment: You cannot do DB-side filtering with your own function. Only EF-supported functions of the DB itself are allowed. Filter results as much as you can on the DB side, then complete filtering on the client side.